# Java Applet Drag and Drop does not work on Mac

Tags: macos, firefox, safari, opera, japplet

My Java applet for File Uploader, the drag and drop does not work in any of the browsers in Mac. Anyone know what is wrong?

I heard that Mac does not support this anymore, but I can't seem to find which version of Mac and Browser to start stopping this function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mac does not support this feature for OSX 10.6.X (and letter) and for all modern browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox). This problem occurs because of implementation of Java Machine on Macs.

Comment: This isn't a metter of a lack of support.  The inability to drag and drop in browsers is due to an issue with Plugin2.  You can read more details here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588455

Comment: Also note that while Apple apparently has no plans to fix this in the near future, there is a workaround: pop the applet out of its frame.  You can do this manually by holding down CMD-Shift and then drag the applet.  If you get creative, you can make this happen automatically when the applet loads on OS X.